# recursive sorting in python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to run a sorting function recursively in python.  I have an empty list that starts everything but everytime I try to print the list I get an empty list.  here is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
def parse(list):
    newParse = []
    if len(list) == 0:
        return newParse
    else:

        x = min(list)

        list.remove(x)
        newParse.append(x)

        return sort(list)
```

Comment: recursion? I can't see the function `parse(list)` called anywhere in the code..

Comment: I'm assuming this is for homework? Because otherwise, you have to know that list objects already have a ``.sort()`` method, that is faster and more efficient than anything you can write yourself in Python.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `newParse` is not preserved between invocations of the function; you're setting it equal to `[]` (well, you're creating a new variable with the value `[]`).

Since the only time you return is

```
newParse = []
if len(list) == 0:
    return newParse`
```

you will always be returning `[]` because that is the value of newParse at that time.

Because you are doing this *recursively*, you are *calling the function anew*, without keeping the function's own state. Take a moment to consider the implications of this on your code.

Instead of initialising `newParse = []`, add an optional parameter `newParse` *defaulting to a bogus value, and set `newParse = []` if you receive that bogus value for newParse. Otherwise, you'll actually be getting the same list every time (i.e. the contents of the list object are being mutated).* And `newParse` through in your tail call.

You also seem to have the problem that your definition and and the supposedly-recursive call refer to different functions.

```
def sort(list, newParse = None):
    if newParse is None:
        newParse = []
    if len(list) == 0:
        return newParse
    else:
        x = min(list)
        list.remove(x)
        newParse.append(x)
        return sort(list, newParse)
```

Comment: Why not just make newParse a global variable?

Comment: @Truerror Because global variables are bad! And also because that would make things worse - we _don't_ want every function call to mutate the single variable `newParse`.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Sorry, I shouldn't have said "global". Really not what I meant. It should be a variable outside the scope of the recursive function, and both the variable and the recursive function could be wrapped in one wrapper function. Something like that. Not global variable. They're evil.

Comment: that would also work. this initially seemed to require less structural change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you are trying to do:

```
def recursive_sort(a_list):
    def helper_function(list_to_be_sorted, list_already_sorted):
        new = []
        if len(list_to_be_sorted) == 0:
            return list_already_sorted
        else:    
            x = min(list_to_be_sorted)    
            list_to_be_sorted.remove(x)
            new.append(x)
            return helper_function(list_to_be_sorted, list_already_sorted + new)
    return helper_function(a_list, [])
```

You shouldn't name variables `list`, as that is a builtin.

Also, if you are trying to implement a recursive sort function, you might want to look at [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), which is a very common (and fast) recursive sorting algorithm. What you have tried to implement is a recursive version of [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), which is much slower.

Also, if you actually need a sorting function, rather than just wanting to implement a recursive one, you should use the list method `sort`, or the function on an iterable `sorted`, both of which will be a lot faster than anything you could make in Python.